# Exchange rate question

Tags: arithmetic

I'm doing this question for my maths homework and I'm pretty sure I got the answer right but it says I got it wrong. (I got the one highlighted in green correct it's the one below that it says is wrong). Just looking for clarification on if I got the question wrong.

For the working I have done 193.75/1.55 = £125.
  £145 - £125 = £20

I have also tried putting 20.00 into the box but that wasn't accepted either.

[image: The Question]

Comment: I get £20 cheaper as well. So the input field is just probably just sensitive. Maybe it wants 20.00, maybe it wants £20.

Comment: Tried 20.00 and it didn't accept that either. It's done the same thing on another question also.

Comment: Maybe they want -20? At this point I'm just guessing.

Comment: I see the same answer, and the same calculation, you did.

Comment: Doesn't like -20 or -20.00 either. Thanks for trying, I just needed to know I wasn't missing something simple.

Comment: Turns out it wanted me to put the £ sign in. Such a pain.

Comment: These automated tests are a pain.  My son wasted hours before realizing that a probability of $.14$ needed to be written as $14\%$, though everything in the problem was written as a decimal and nothing was written as a percent.

Comment: @lulu I would have written $ 0.14 $, which probably would not have been accepted. I would not have had the idea to write $ .14 $- in the first few hours.

Comment: @callculus  We tried $0.14$, and so on.  The problem was fairly difficult so we both figured there was a flaw in the calculation. I did it myself, then redid it, then did it a different way.  The frustration level was unbelievable.  He figured out the percent thing himself, I never would have.  I never think of probabilities as percents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone else uses the site "MathsWatch" for their homework. It wanted me to put a "£" sign in the answer even though it says the units in the question.